# How can I render the entire video in Blender VSE?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm making a video project in the VSE.
My video is 3 minutes long however, when I render it I only get up to 10 seconds or less.

[image: blender screen shot]

It only reaches up to that part of the video. 
What can I do?
Do I need to select any specific settings to get the entire video to play it or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Under the dimensions tab you have frame range set from 1 to 250. Try to increase that to 9357.

Comment: I don't understand, why in your Timeline the End Frame (which is set properly) doesn't match the same setting in the Properties Area under Dimensions... it should automatically be synchronised.

Comment: @Mahinsa: I just found it out by accident as I clicked around in one of my Movie projects... I updated my answer below. You need to uncheck this Setting "Scene.use_preview_range" in your Timeline/VSE.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the *End Frame* in the render settings.
[image: animation render settings]
If you are rendering at 24 frames per second, and since you have a 3 minute video you will need to set the *End Frame* to 4320.

---

You also will want to change the render *Resolution* (it is right next to the frame range), now you have it set to 960x540, full HD is 1920x1080 but with the scale set to *100%*.

Read the [video Encoding](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/render/output/properties/output.html#encoding) section of the blender manual for more information, or the 2.79 [manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/output/video.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can set your End Frame visually by selecting the last non-black Frame of your footage in the VSE and then hovering your mouse over the Timeline and pressing <kbd>E</kbd> for End Frame (as indicated in the Frame menu) or <kbd>S</kbd> for Start Frame to set it as your current frame (that's the green vertical line in the VSEs *Sequencer View* and in the *Timeline*).

But make sure, as in your case you did this "wrong", that you unselect the "**Use an alternative start/end frame range for animation playback and OpenGL renders instead of the Render properties start/end frame range**".
[image: use_preview_range Tooltip]

As you can see in your Screenshot, you checked it:
[image: VSE & Timeline Screenshot]

This causes your unwanted behaviour.

If it's checked, your *Timeline Frame Range* Settings only effect Playback (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), but when you render your Movie (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>), the *Render Properties Frame Range* will be used (both differ in your case 9357/250).

The 250 Frames are just 10.4 seconds (or 10 Seconds plus 10 Frames, you already stepped one frame backwards in your screenshot to 10+09) which were rendered in your case. The 9357 are nearly 6:30 mins, so this should be reduced to about 24 frames/sec * 60 sec/min * 3 min = 4320 Frames.
**Uncheck `use_preview_range`** and then your End Frame in your Timeline should show 250 as well as it is now set to in your Render Properties. You then need to **set your End Frame to** approximately the mentioned **4320** and you're fine.

Oh and usually you should set your Start Frame to 1, not 0. ;-) *This makes your End Frame show/match your actual Numbers of Frames, else you need to increase it by one to get your final Frame Amount.*