# When I render my video, the resulting file is only 30 seconds and not the minute and a half its supposed to be

Tags: rendering, video

The video is in 1080p and starts at frame 300 and ends at frame 1202. The video itself is in 29.97 fps. Anti-Aliasing is at 8 and the video is saved as a Xvid. It is using RGB. The bit rate is set to 7992. 
My computer has a Geforce 1060 6gb Graphics card and an i5 Processor.

[image: Settings Screenshot]

Thanks,
-Austin

Comment: It would be better to include a screeny of the project settings (or sample blend file) otherwise its a bit difficutl to diagnose.

Comment: @3pointedit I took a screenshot of the settings and uploaded it to http://imgur.com/a/S3TT7 . If you need anything else to help me just ask.

Comment: Starting at 300 and ending at 1202 gives 903 frames. 903 frames/(29.97 frames/second) gives 30.130130130... seconds.

Comment: @Duane Dibbley Thanks, I didn't notice that. I have no idea why it was set to that.

Comment: I didn't see your screenshot until after I posted my comment. I see that you also have a time remapping set. The values you have set, 108 to 100, would actually speed the video up by 8%, but still render the number of frames you set in start and end frame. [This quick tutorial](https://youtu.be/3dE-485zoCw) explains the time remapping fairly well, but it shows slow motion instead of fast motion.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43779/2843